# Cannot find the error in my code, possibly has to do with how I manage the Branch class

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

When I finally thought I had the concept of classes learned, I tried to make a simple visualisation to confirm it. However, I run the code and nothing shows... probably just a simple wrong variable or something, but it's been driving me nuts for 2 hours and counting:

```
class Branch{
    constructor(orix, oriy, lifespan){
        this.orix = orix;
        this.oriy = oriy;
        this.x = orix;
        this.y = oriy;
        this.lifespan = lifespan;
    }
    update(){
        if(this.lifespan>0){
            this.nx = this.x + random(-1,1);
            this.ny = this.y + random(-1,0.1);
            lifespan--;
            stroke(256);
            strokeWeight(10);
            point(this.x,this.y);
            point(this.nx,this.ny);
            this.x = this.nx;
            this.y = this.ny;
            return this.x, this.y
        }
    }
}

class Tree{
    constructor(orx, ory){
        this.orx = orx;
        this.ory = ory;
        this.branches = [new Branch(this.orx, this.ory)];
    }
    update(){
        this.branches.forEach((branch)=>branch.update());
        if(this.branches.length<25){
            this.branches.forEach((branch)=>{if(random(10)>7.5){this.branches.push(new Branch(branch.update(),random(20)))}});
        }
    }
}
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    giantree = new Tree(width/2,height);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    giantree.update();
}
```

Comment: @derpirscher This is processing, its engine calls these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `draw()` function only calls the `update()` function of the `giantree` object, which is of class `Tree`. The `update()` function in `Tree` iterates over all `Branch`es and calls the `update()`.

All the drawings in `Branch` are encapuslated by `if(this.lifespan>0){` but your line `this.branches = [new Branch(this.orx, this.ory)];` in the constructor of `Tree` does not set a `lifespan` variabel. Therefore it is `undefined` and the code is never executed.